# Understand the Spring ecosystem and differences with JSF/Primefaces

Tags: spring

I know JAVA JEE and PRIMEFACES.

I never read anything on SPRING or Struts, but now I want to well understand that for a new project.

Comment: start read anything on [Spring.](https://spring.io/) On their website is everything you need for fast understanding. For deep understanding you have to investigate more time. I recommend to use `Spring-boot`

Comment: I don't know if spring-boot will make me well understand the Spring Framework, particularly the Spring MVC. In fact i'm intersted in writing a web app that could access data, with EJB 3 from JEE stack, and make some CRUD operations. Ideally, I want to couple it with AngularJS and my favourite IDE is netbeans. I would expect a clear simple tutorial if someone can have a link.

Comment: watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBwlgvfllNk) for a fast understanding what spring-boot can do. Spring boot includes all spring projects like MVC, Spring-Data, Rest... And you are free to couple angularJs or some template engines like thymeleaf. EJB3 you dont need with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Spring core is main building block for Spring Framework. Try to learn the spring Core concepts like IOC,DI(Dependency Injection), Wiring of Beans. How spring will manages Beans in containers once u get it idea on this others modules may be easy for u. bcoz for other modules spring core is base I suggest u to go through the spring doc.

Answer (score 0):

Spring framework is used to achieve the loose coupling between the modules and it is basically used for the dependency injection.

I would suggest you to first read Spring Dependency injection and Inversion of control topics for better understanding of the framework. Go through Spring documentation for more details of the concepts.